# Pyautogui hotkey command not working in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

On Pycharm in Mac, I am using Pyautogui to perform simple operation of Select all with Command+A using `hotkey()` function.

The code works in scenario:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press("b")

pyautogui.hotkey("command", "a")

# Cursor here: b
```

with all text selected. But does not work in the scenario:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey("command", "a")

# Cursor here: a
```

where it simply prints the second key in the hotkey which is `a`

Same thing happens when I do it in Atom. Can someone explain what’s wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In mac os, actually you need to press command key first before any key for the hotkey, so you need to add interval between them.

```
pyautogui.hotkey("command", "a", interval=0.25 )
pyautogui.hotkey("command", "r", interval=0.25 )  #to refresh page
pyautogui.hotkey("command", "t", interval=0.25 )  #new tab
```

etc.

Comment: Nice!  Seems to work down to `interval=0.05` for me, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

give it `time.sleep(0.1)` may work.

If still don't work, try the hard way:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('command')
pyautogui.keyDown('a')
pyautogui.keyUp('command')
pyautogui.keyUp('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that on MacOS you now need to explicitly grand access to other apps that need to control the keyboard.

You do that by going to Security Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility - Give permissions to your terminal application.

Since you were able to control the keyboard somewhat in your case this might not apply to your particular case.